# how to substitute a hash key value in another hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have two arrays of hashes:

```
a = [{"a" => 1}, {"b" => [10, 9, 11]}, {"c" => [8, 9]}, {"d" => [7, 1, 1]}]
b = [{"k" => 1}, {"l" => "c"}, {"m" => "a"}, {"n" => "b"}, {"o" => 2}]
```

If a hash in `b` contains a value that is a key in one of the hashes in `a`, I want to replace that value with the value of the corresponding key in `a`. For example, in `{"l"=>"c"}` in `b`, the value `"c"` is the key in `{"c" => [8, 9]}` in `a`, so I wish to replace the value `"c"` in `{"l" => "c"}`with the array `[8,9]`. On the other hand, the value `1` in `{"k" => 1}` in `b` is not a key in any of the hashes in `a`, so it is to be left unchanged.
I want the result to be as follows:

```
result #=> [{"k" => 1}, {"l" => [8, 9]}, {"m" => 1},
       #    {"n" => [10, 9, 11]}, {o => 2}]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Also should `{"b" => 10,9.11}` be `{"b" => [10, 9, 11]}`? Your way is not a valid hash.

Comment: yes Beartech, u r correct there, its array there.

Comment: You need to edit your question to make several corrections: 1) I assume all keys and values that are letters should be in quotes.  I count 7 corrections required (`"c"`, `"d"`, and so on), plus 5 more in `result`. 2) I presume `10,9,11` is an array, in which case it must be written `[10,9,11]`. Same for the values of `"c"` and `"d"` in `a` and of `"l"` and `"n"` in `result`.

Comment: In addition to Cary's point, the [ruby-on-rails] tag should be deleted.

Comment: pardon my ignorance..here if aim wrong.... don't we use ruby code in ruby on rails ??? Don't  we use hashes in controllers of ROR

Comment: Yes, But this question has nothing to do with Rails. It is plain Ruby Hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Hash out of `a` merging all the elements.

```
hsh = a.inject(:merge)
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>[10, 9, 11], "c"=>[8, 9], "d"=>[7, 1, 1]}
```

Then call map on `b`, just like in Cary's solution.

```
b.map do |h|
  k,v = h.to_a.first
  { k => hsh.key?(v) ? hsh[v] : v }
end
# => [{"k"=>1}, {"l"=>[8, 9]}, {"m"=>1}, {"n"=>[10, 9, 11]}, {"o"=>2}]
```

Comment: I must remember that use of `inject`. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve your objective:

```
a = [{"a"=>1},{"b"=>[10,9,11]},{"c"=>[8,9]},{"d"=>[7,1,1]}]
b = [{"k"=>1},{"l"=>"c"},{"m"=>"a"},{"n"=>"b"},{"o"=>2}]

h = a.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g.keys.first] = g.values.first }
  #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>[10, 9, 11], ["c1", "c2", "c3"]=>[8, 9], ["d1"]=>[7, 1, 1]} 
b.map do |g|
  k,v = g.to_a.first 
  { k => h.key?(v) ? h[v] : v }
end
  #=> [{"k"=>1}, {"l"=>[8, 9]}, {"m"=>1}, {"n"=>[10, 9, 11]}, {"o"=>2}]
```